# Drupal Table with Radios

Tags: forms, drupal, radio-button, tabular

How can I add 'radios' into a form built around theme_table?

Using a single 'checkbox' or single 'radio' seems to work fine, but as soon as I use 'radios' no radio buttons render at all.

From another Stack Overflow question, I've seen `form_process_radios()` mentioned, and using this actually shows the radio buttons. But they are no longer tied together, and all of them can be put into an 'on' state at once.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Simple answer: you cannot easily. (Allthough you may have success with defining your own processor, using expand_radios, hardcore stuff!).

Longer answer: `radios` uses [theme_radios](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--form.inc/function/theme_radios/6). And as you can see, that uses a single DIV-wrapper, which makes it impossible to spread out radios over a table.

What you could best do, is create a hierarchical form, whith one `radio` per option. Avoid `radios`. By grouping them hierarchically the `name` will be the same, which is the way [radios are grouped](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#radio).

```
# from install.php:
  foreach ($names as $profile => $name) {
    $form['profile'][$name] = array(
      '#type' => 'radio',
      '#value' => 'default',
      '#return_value' => $profile,
      '#title' => $name,
      '#description' => isset($profiles[$profile]['description']) ? $profiles[$profile]['description'] : '',
      '#parents' => array('profile'),
    );
  }
```

Then, in the theme-function where you build the table around the form, you render each radio in the appropriate table-cell.

Answer (score 6):

So to use Berkes advice you would have to use the '#atributes' property, with the same name for all your radio elements of the same group.

like this:

```
'#attributes' => array('name' => array('somename'))
```

This is a more complete example:

```
for ($i = 0; $i < $num; $i++){
  $element[$i]['answer'] = array(
    '#type' => 'textfield',
    '#title' => t('Answer'),
  );
  $element[$i]['correct'] = array(
      '#type' => 'radio',
      '#value' => 'default',
      '#return_value' => $i,
      '#title' => t('Correct answer'),
      '#attributes' => array('name' => array('correct-answer')),
  );
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Here's a Drupal 7 example of how I got radio buttons inside a table so that they were easy to work with:

```
$form['item']['table_start'] = array(
  '#markup' => '<table><thead><tr><th>Header 1</th><th>Header 2</th></tr></thead><tbody>'
);
for ($i = 1; $i < 3; $i++) {
  $form['item']['tr_start_'.$i] = array('#markup' => '<tr>');
  $form['item'][$i]['item'] = array(
    '#type' => 'radio',
    '#title' => t('Title'),
    '#return_value' => $i,
    '#prefix' => '<td>',
    '#suffix' => '</td>',
  );
  $form['item']['item_'.$i] = array('#markup' => '<td>'. $i .'</td>');
  $form['item']['tr_end_'.$i] = array('#markup' => '</tr>');
}
$form['item']['table_end'] = array('#markup' => '</tbody></table>');
```

This allowed me to render the whole table part of the form in my template file with `<?php print drupal_render($form['item']); ?>` and get the selected radio button value in the validation and submit handlers with `$form_state['values']['item']`. The radio buttons already had the same name attribute and were thus linked together without the need to manually specify it.

Comment: @volocuga The existence of theme_table() does not mean that building tables via other means is automatically "shit". Drupal 7 introduced a 'tableselect' FAPI element, but it does not cover all use cases and I currently don't know how to implement this with theme_table(). In case you do it would be significantly more helpful to write it as an answer here rather than badmouthing my not-perfect-but-solid-and-working solution.

Comment: Yes, I can understand that this is a little messy, however this solution works straight out the box and is quick and easy. Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

I think for example you should to read this form callback: [node_admin_nodes](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--node--node.admin.inc/function/node_admin_nodes/6) from node.admin.inc

Comment: That's irrelevant, as far as I can see. It is neither a table, nor about radio's.

Answer (score 0):

You need [to use this](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!form.inc/function/theme_tableselect/7) `theme_tableselect` function